# Understanding cuthill mckee clustering

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, networkx, linear-algebra, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to reduce the bandwidth of the entries in the adjacency matrix of a graph via Cuthill-McKee
algorithm.

I have the following input graph and I could get the permutation order.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.utils import reverse_cuthill_mckee_ordering, cuthill_mckee_ordering

G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=30, m=55, seed=1)
nxpos = nx.spring_layout(G, dim=2, iterations=10000)
nx.set_node_attributes(G, nxpos, 'pos')
rcm = list(cuthill_mckee_ordering(G))
```

Next, I relabelled the nodes of the original graph

```
d = OrderedDict(zip(G.nodes(), rcm))
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=d)
H_adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(H, nodelist=range(len(H.nodes())))
plt.spy(H_adj)
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, the adjacency matrix `H_adj` is not banded

[image]

On the other hand, when I try the below `G_adj_rcm` is banded.

```
 G_adj_rcm = nx.adjacency_matrix(G, nodelist=rcm)
 plt.spy(G_adj_rcm)
 plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm not sure if the relabelling is incorrect or if I am failing to understand how the algorithm works. Clarifications on why `H_adj` is not banded will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relabelling is wrong. You need to relabel the nodes according to their position in `rcm`. The following mapping works.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from networkx.utils import cuthill_mckee_ordering
G = nx.gnm_random_graph(n=30, m=55, seed=1)
rcm = list(cuthill_mckee_ordering(G))

d = {node:rcm.index(node) for node in G}
H = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping=d)
H_adj = nx.adjacency_matrix(H,nodelist=range(30))
plt.spy(H_adj)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you, I misinterpreted `rcm`. `nodelist=range(30)` was the catch, unlike MATLAB the node ordering is not sorted in Networkx.